# ping 192.168.0.1 | awk '{print $1} '

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

```
ping 192.168.0.1 | awk '{print $1}'
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I am creating a script that does some task. So, i wanted to display appropriate error message upon invalid hostname or errors generated by ping command.

I thought of modifying errors generated using the above mentioned command. What i wanted to do was to print just the error not 'ping' but that doesn't happen. Can anyone tell me the remedy for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ping` just for determining whether the given hostname is reachable or not, then you can do this:

```
if ping -c 1 "$otherhost" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'The host "%s" is reachable\n' "$otherhost"
else
    printf 'The host "%s" is not reachable\n' "$otherhost"
fi
```

This sends a single `ECHO_REQUEST` packet to the host given in `"$otherhost"` and uses the exit status of `ping` to determine whether the utility managed to perform its task or not.  All ordinary output from `ping` is discarded.

Note that if `ping` is unable to query another host, this does not mean that the host is definitely down or not routable.  It may simply be ignoring the `ECHO_REQUEST` packet.

---

If you want to output the actual error produced by `ping` on failure you can do this in the following way to avoid having to call the utility twice (since network errors are sometimes transient, a second invocation of `ping` may not be failing or may be failing in a different way):

```
pingerr=$(mktemp)
if ping -c 1 "$otherhost" >/dev/null 2>"$pingerr"; then
    printf 'The host "%s" is reachable\n' "$otherhost"
else
    printf 'The host "%s" is not reachable\n' "$otherhost"
    if [ -s "$pingerr" ]; then
        echo 'ping error:'
        cat "$pingerr"
    fi
fi
rm -f "$pingerr"
```

This saves any diagnostic messages from `ping` in a temporary file which later gets outputted if `ping` fails (if there is anything in it at all, which is what the `-s` test tests for).  The file will always be created (even if it remains empty), so we remove it after the `if`-statement.

Using this method, you may also parse the error output file in whatever way you want.  For example:

```
pingerr=$(mktemp)
if ping -c 1 "$otherhost" >/dev/null 2>"$pingerr"; then
    printf 'The host "%s" is reachable\n' "$otherhost"
else
    printf 'The host "%s" is not reachable\n' "$otherhost"
    if [ -s "$pingerr" ]; then
        printf 'ping says'
        sed 's/^[^:]*//' <"$pingerr"
    fi
fi
rm -f "$pingerr"
```

Here, instead of just outputting the original message from `ping`, we remove the bit before the first `:` before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to define and capture everything you want to work with as a variable:

1. `$CMD_PING` - The command you want to evaluate (as a variable it's easier to execute it and capture results as desired)
2. `$CODE_EXIT` - The exit code returned when `$CMD_PING` is evaluated (will be something other than `0` if an error occurred)

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD_PING="ping -c1 does-not-exist"
EXEC_PING="$( $CMD_PING >/dev/null 2>&1 )" # STDOUT and STDERR go to /dev/null
CODE_EXIT="$?"
if [ ! 0 -eq "$CODE_EXIT" ]; then
        # echo error only (or capture error for parsing)
        # capture example: EXEC_PING="$( $CMD_PING >/dev/null )"
        $CMD_PING >/dev/null # STDOUT goes to /dev/null, only STDERR prints
        exit 1
fi
echo "success"
```

Comment: why downvote ? this code is valid.

Comment: I up-voted this answer. This works, and it does exactly what the OP said they wanted.

Comment: EXEC_PING is unused?

Comment: `EXEC_PING` is there more for an example of subshell output capture than anything - the OP seemed interested in parsing STDERR, so I figured an example couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

The only way in which your idea could work is if the error output (stderr) is exchanged with stdout to send the error values to awk (using a non-existent address):

```
$ ping -c4 invalid.local. 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | awk '{print "Error ==> " $0}'
Error ==> ping: unknown host
```

But the exit status will become the exit of awk, which should be usually success (0).

If all you want is to receive the error and act on the exit status of ping, you may use:

```
$ ping -c4 invalid.local. 2>&1 1>&- ; echo $?
ping: unknown host
1

$ ping -c4 127.0.0.1 2>&1 1>&- ; echo $?
0
```

So, the test could be:

```
if ping -c3 -w5 domain.com 2>&1 1>&- ; then 
    echo "ping was successful"
else
    echo "ping failed with code $?"
fi
```